# Silent refresh in Angular-ouath2-oidc not working after id_token expiration

Tags: angular, adfs, openid-connect, angular-oauth2-oidc

My current Angular 7 PWA application can't renew the OIDC tokens (obtained via **azure adfs**) after the `id_token` it's expired: all the `silentRefresh()` calls fails with following error:
 `AADSTS50058:A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in`

All the `silentRefresh()` operation within the `id_token` expiration time performs, instead, successfully.

My OauthService initialization is below:

```js
 init() {
    this.oauthService.events.subscribe(e => e instanceof OAuthErrorEvent ? console.error(e) : console.warn(e));
    this.oauthService.configure({...APP_CONFIG.auth.OIDC.config,
      postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
      requestAccessToken: true,
      showDebugInformation: true,
      strictDiscoveryDocumentValidation: false,
      responseType: 'id_token token',
      silentRefreshRedirectUri: window.location.origin + '/silent-refresh.html',
    });
    this.oauthService.tokenValidationHandler = new JwksValidationHandler();
    this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocument();
    this.oauthService.setupAutomaticSilentRefresh();
  }
```

`APP_CONFIG.auth.OIDC.config` stores all the endpoints that are not relevant for the question.

How can i resolve this situation? i followed this [answer](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/323#issuecomment-230959217) on github and, in fact, can't see any cookie stored in my application domain, even though all the response contains `Set-Cookie=` headers. Maybe the problem is related to the missing cookies in my application domain?